# sum of all the values from that row

Tags: r, sum

If I have a dataset with a column as shown below

```
 Col1
 1.080042
 1.083287
 1.141108
 1.191246
 1.117395
```

What I want to create is a another column Col2 like this

```
 Col1        Col2
 1.080042    1.080042/(1.080042 + 1.083287 + 1.141108 + 1.191246 + 1.117395)
 1.083287    1.083287/(1.083287 + 1.141108 + 1.191246 + 1.117395) 
 1.141108    1.141108/(1.141108 + 1.191246 + 1.117395)
 1.191246    1.191246/(1.191246 + 1.117395) 
 1.117395    1.117395 /1.117395
```

Col2 is Col1 value divided by the sum of Co1 values below it. I am not sure how to achieve this efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the cumulative sum of `rev`erse elements of 'Col1', get the `rev`erse and divide by 'Col1'

```
df1$Col2 <- df1$Col1/rev(cumsum(rev(df1$Col1)))
df1$Col2
#[1] 0.1924153 0.2389760 0.3307800 0.5159945 1.0000000
```

-checking with OP's calculation

```
1.080042/(1.080042 + 1.083287 + 1.141108 + 1.191246 + 1.117395)
#[1] 0.1924153

1.083287/(1.083287 + 1.141108 + 1.191246 + 1.117395) 
#[1] 0.238976
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(1.080042, 1.083287, 1.141108, 1.191246, 
1.117395)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyverse) # dplyr and purrr

df %>% 
  mutate(Col2 = Col1/accumulate(Col1, `+`, .dir = 'backward'))

#       Col1      Col2
# 1 1.080042 0.1924153
# 2 1.083287 0.2389760
# 3 1.141108 0.3307800
# 4 1.191246 0.5159945
# 5 1.117395 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution besides `cumsum` by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61260277/12158757)

```
df <- within(df,Col2 <- Col1/rev(Reduce(`+`,rev(Col1),accumulate = TRUE)))
```

such that

```
> df
      Col1      Col2
1 1.080042 0.1924153
2 1.083287 0.2389760
3 1.141108 0.3307800
4 1.191246 0.5159945
5 1.117395 1.0000000
```